# Automatic Order Date Change when order is completed Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there some solution to automatically change order date when order in completed in woocommerce?

Comment: Which date you want to update: the order creation date, the modified date, the paid date or the compete date? And with what value or what time?

Answer (score 0):

You can not alter the order date as it is a creation date of the order, and retrieves the post date of creation.
You may try with this:

```
global $post;
$post->post_date = date_i18n("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
```

//it will just render the today's date

for order status, you may use the hook **"woocommerce_order_status_changed"**.